# Secure in-app purchases of video content in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a relative simple business model yet I cant really figure out how to solve it:

I have hundreds of small videos that I produce and some of the videos must be paid to be watched. 
I dont want the users to need a login. They just need their apple id to pay for the content. That way I dont need to server code.

I was thinking of using in-app purchases but:

1) Where do I host my videos? I think its best that they can be streamed.

2) How do I secure my videos so that people doesnt just share the urls (which they can get from a web debugger)?

3) Optional: Do you know a simple (maybe free) server for hosting a tree structure of data (in my case video categories)?

Answer (score 0):

you can upload your video on youtube or on Vimeo in private channel. so no one can view that video without your permission. Then you can write code to play that private video.

Another way is you can host your own server and upload video over there. To stream video you can your server need access token. which your server has provided while login. in the way you can also prevent the user not to play video without paying you.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want the users to need a login. Sorry, I've updated my question. And I also want to keep it simpel, so that I dont need server logic.

Comment: When you make in app purchase. you will get receipt date.when you validate that receipt. Apple will give you some unique id's for that receipt. you can use that id as your access token.